# Why my fourier transform is not working properly?

Tags: python, numpy, classification, signals, fft

So, I'm trying to plot the fourier transform of an EEG signal, I usually use the complete signal which comes in a numpy array of this shape: **samples,channels**, for example (69440, 16), that's easy and the plot looks great. But then I started working without a complete signal but classes, which is kind of the signal in pieces, also as a numpy array of this shape: **samples,channels,observations** for example [500, 16, 40].

My teacher told me the best was to get the Fourier transform of each observation (500x16x0, 500x16x1, ..., 500x16x39) and promediate the transforms of all observations.

This is the python function I wrote to get the transform, it tries to manage the signal as the classes (class1 and class2 concatenated), if it fails it means the given signal is the complete one, the problem is that when I plot the transforms, the numbers of the **y** axis in the plot are much higher when I use the classes than when I use the complete signal.

Any idea why this is happening?
By the way, sampling frequency is obviously the same for either the complete Signal or the classes.

```
def analysis(signal_to_transform):
    sign = signal_to_transform #Given signal
    try:
        observartions = len(sign[0,0,:]) # Pieces (Observations)
        n = len(sign[:,0,0]) #Size of the signal
    except IndexError:
        observartions = 1 # 1 because it's the complete signal which isn't cut in pieces
        n = len(sign[:,0]) #Size of the signal
    freqs = sampling_frequency*fftfreq(n)
    mask = freqs>0
    for i in range(0,number_of_channels):
      fft_Y = 0
      for j in range(0,observartions):
        y = None
        try:
          y = sign[:,i,j]
        except IndexError:
          y = sign[:,i]
        fft_y = 2*np.abs((fft(y)/n))
        fft_Y = fft_Y + fft_y
      fft_Y = fft_Y/observartions
      plt.figure(1)
      plt.title('Fourier transform')
      plt.plot(freqs[mask],fft_Y[mask],label='fourier')
    plt.show()
```

**Fourier transform of complete signal** shape: (69440, 16)

[image: Fourier transform of complete signal]

**Fourier transform of promediated classes** shape: (1375, 16, 40)

[image]

Comment: I don't remember Fourier transform so I will just throw this wild guess... isn't that precisely why you take in account the different observations? is that not an expected behavior?

Comment: @martineau I will check, to be honest I am not very good at signal processing yet, the problem is that I need to plot this to apply the correct filters and then use it for pattern recognition. Which is givibg terrible results if I filter based on the classes plot, that's why I tougth I'm simply doing the transform incorrectly on the classes

Comment: Armando: I think you must be replying to @RichieV.

Comment: perhaps the guys from https://math.stackexchange.com/ can help as well